# Quasar does not run on localhost:8080

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I run a quasar project "quasar dev" and it run without any error (see the log), but in the browser "http://localhost:8080" shows an empty screen. No calls, no result.

[image]

If I open "0.0.0.0:8080" it tries to start but without success.

[image]

Why does it happen? How to run the project on "localhost:8080"?

Comment: something is wrong, conceptually  0.0.0.0 means than all ip address can use  this port and localhost is one of them,

Comment: Which browser are you using. In my case if the browser is not in the browserslist it also shows a blank page.

Comment: I tried Firefox, Chrome, Safari. What is browserlist? Where can I find it?

Comment: @podeig sorry for my late answer. You find it in your package.json. Look at quasar page also https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/browser-compatibility#Introduction

Comment: Hi, did anyone figure out what the problem was?